# What is a "standard symbol" in analysis?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, terminology

I was reading some Wikipedia pages about analysis when I came across this strange "standard symbol" terminology in the "[Fourier integral operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_integral_operator)" page.

It seems to be a function (or a distribution) since it is said to be "compactly supported" in some variable.

I also came across the word "symbole principal" which is french for "principal symbol", in a [paper](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIF/AIF_1979__29_2/AIF_1979__29_2_223_0/AIF_1979__29_2_223_0.pdf) about analysis (in French.)

What are "symbol" and "principal symbol" in analysis?

EDIT: Ok, it seems I had to find the right combination of words to get a successful search in Google. [Here it is for whoever is interested.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_of_a_differential_operator)